# Set width of FormField and PlainTextContentControl

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table and its width is to fit the size of the window.

I've a couple of  FormField and PlainTextContentControls used in this table.

But the FormField text input fields are small in width by default.

I want the size of these FormField text input fields to fit the size of this cell.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong (*And I could be wrong*), the `formfields` have a predefined size and expand only when you fill the data in. There is no predefined setting which you can set to increase the width.

**Alternative way to increase the width.**

1. Increasing the font size of it but this will also increase the height of the `formfield`.
2. Fill the `Default Text` with spaces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, 

But, these are not the solutions that I am looking for :(
 
Because, if we use spaces user can click right in center of the formfield and start entering texts which will leave unwanted spaces in the beginning and ending. 

That is why I was looking for something like "Formfield1.width=200" etc.

Comment: Like I mentioned AFAIK, there is no predefined setting which you can set to increase the width.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for confirming that.